# youtube data API v3 is deprecated

Tags: youtube

I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 in my project to retrieve videos from YouTube and display them on my website. However, I'm encountering a "404 error - not found" when trying to fetch the videos. After reviewing the YouTube API documentation, I noticed that they have deprecated the use of POST requests for this purpose. Does anyone have an alternative solution to address this issue?

I have tried reviewing the official documentation and now I'm seeking for alternative solution to retrieve videos data from YouTube.

Comment: Provide the request leading to the 404 error.